# How to check if a method has been overridden in a data class object in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, methods, overriding, data-class

My problem is differentiating the methods created by the data class with the methods created manually by the person.

I'm trying to find a way to differentiate the methods created by the data class with the methods created by the person to create generic functions. (Ex: toString())
I've already tried using "declaringClass", but it only resolves to class and not to data class.

Comment: Please show some examples of what you mean by "differentiating the methods created by the data class with the methods created manually by the person". Also, what do you have as input? A `KClass` object?

Comment: Maybe you can take a step back and explain what you're trying to accomplish by doing this so we can understand the problem and how it might be solved.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.